# Qual alternativa usar ao invés de document.write

Tags: javascript

Diz-se que document.write não é uma boa prática, e também não funciona após window.onload, que é o caso que preciso. Eu tenho a seguinte função que preciso trocar o document.write, o detalhe é que preciso que o conteudo seja adicionado na mesma tag/elemento que está a chamada da função dento da tag , sem que o elemento pai seja sempre o mesmo.

```
function GerarSWF($arquivo,$largura,$altura,$id){
    document.writeln(' <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="' + $id + '" data="' + $arquivo + '" width="' + $largura + '" height="' + $altura + '">'); 
    document.writeln(' <param name="movie" value="' + $arquivo + '" />'); 
    document.writeln(' <param name="menu" value="false" />');
    document.writeln(' <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />');
    document.writeln(' <embed src="' + $arquivo + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" menu="false" quality="high" id="' + $id + '" width="' + $largura + '" height="' + $altura + '"></embed>');
    document.writeln(' </object>');
}
```

exemplo da situação:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="pode_nem_sempre_ser_o_mesmo">
  <div>
    <script>GerarSWF(bla,bla);
    //o conteudo tem q ficar dentro dessa div q está o <script>
    //mas pode aparecer em locais diversos, nem sempre saberei o id ou tag
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

tem como fazer isso?
desde já agradeço a atenção

Comment: Já experimentaste o `innerHTML` ?

Comment: Você pode colocar um id na div?

Comment: Se bem que neste caso específico o `document.write` deve funcionar.

Comment: @Edison, eu não sei como fazer isso sem especificar o id, tem como?

Comment: @bfavaretto, a chamada vem de dentro de artigos e já mtos já, não teria como mudar isso. Então, não tem como mudar e colocar um id, as vezes até tem , mas como disse não é sempre o mesmo

Comment: [Tem como identificar o bloco `<script>` que está rodando](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10810130), mas [nem sempre isso funciona](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14410368).

Comment: De onde vem esse codigo? do servidor? PHP? porque não gerar o HTML já com tudo, em vez de fazer JavaScript que vai escrever o HTML? Explica um pouco melhor de onde vem o código para percebermos.

Comment: a função está dentro de um arquivo.js carregado com tag async. Essa função ja está dentro de centenas de artigos em um banco de dados. Portanto alterar cada uma não é uma alternativa mto viavel
como alterei o carregamento do arquivo.js a pouco tempo, estou tendo q fazer alguns ajustes e esse é o ultimo. No caso eu tenho q renomear a função dentro do arquivo.js pra Gerarsfw2 e na pagina tenho q criar a function GerarSFW(){window.load=GerarSFW2();}
. Isso pq qdo o arquivo.js é carregado async, não dá pra saber qdo ele será concluido e isso pode ocorrer depois da função ser chamada, o qdaria erro

Comment: Podes mostrar a função php que gera esse HTML exemplo? como é que `GerarSWF($arquivo,$largura,$altura,$id)` recebe esses argumentos?

Comment: é em asp, mas não tem programação  em asp pertinente nesse trecho. é um conteudo em um campo de um banco de dado q contem um artigo basicamente com texto e html, no caso qdo alguem usa imagem ou flash pelo editor de conteudo, o editor insere esse codigo, eu até poderia muda-lo mas só mudaria os novos e teria um trabalho danado para alterar os antigos q já estão lá

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for possível não declarar uma tag `script` chamando a função para adicionar o HTML à `div` em que se encontra. Você pode tentar criando uma `div` com atributos customizados e a partir disso buscar os elementos que possuam os atributos e adicionar o HTML, segue exemplo.

Você pode inspecionar o HTML para visualizar como ficou.

```js
// Função para criar os SWF.
function appendSWF() {
  
  // Busca todos elementos com atribuito gera-swf.
  var swfs = document.querySelectorAll('[gera-swf]');
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(swfs, function(arr) {
    var eObj = document.createElement('object'),
       eParam1 = document.createElement('param'),
       eParam2 = document.createElement('param'),
       eParam3 = document.createElement('param'),
       eEmbed = document.createElement('embed'),
        eData = arr.getAttribute('swf-data'),
        eId = arr.getAttribute('swf-id'),
        eWidth = arr.getAttribute('swf-width'),
        eHeight = arr.getAttribute('swf-height');
    
    // Define atribuito estáticos.
    eObj.type = "application/x-shockware-flash";
    eParam1.name = 'movie';
    eParam2.name = 'menu';
    eParam2.value = 'false';
    eParam3.name = 'wmode';
    eParam3.value = 'transparent';
    eEmbed.type = "application/x-shockware-flash";
    eEmbed.wmode = 'transparent';
    eEmbed.menu = 'false';
    eEmbed.quality = 'high';
    
    // Define os atributos e seus valores no elemento Object.
    eObj.data = eData;
  eObj.id = eId;
    eObj.width = eWidth;
    eObj.height = eHeight;
    
    // Seta os atributos aos elementos param e adiciona ao elemento Object.
    eParam1.value = eData;
    eObj.appendChild(eParam1);
    eObj.appendChild(eParam2);
    eObj.appendChild(eParam3);
    
    // Seta os atributos ao elemento embed e adiciona ao elemento Object.
    eEmbed.src = eData;
    eEmbed.id = eId;
    eEmbed.width = eWidth;
    eEmbed.height = eHeight;
    eObj.appendChild(eEmbed);
    
    // Adiciona o elemento Object a div[gera-swf].
    
    arr.appendChild(eObj);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', appendSWF);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div gera-swf swf-data="text.txt" swf-id="1" swf-width="100" swf-height="100"></div>
<div gera-swf swf-data="file.txt" swf-id="2" swf-width="25" swf-height="25"></div>
```

> Veja também no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/2xb8gb2p/)

**@Edit** Conforme mencionado nos comentários a necessidade de ser um elemento script com a chamada da função.

Desenvolvi este outro script, vou explica-lo. Ele pega todas as tags `script` dentro do `body` verifica quais possuem a palavra `GerarSWF` e seus respectivos parâmetros, se possuírem os valores correspondentes, cria a estrutura `object` com `param` e `embed` e adiciona à tag `script` em questão, após isso, remove a tag `script`. Acredito não ser uma das melhores alternativas, talvez se ajustar e ou melhorar algumas funcionalidades no script ele fique melhor.

```html
<script>
function GerarSWF(pId, pFile, pWidth, pHeight) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allElements, function(arr) {
      if(arr.textContent.indexOf('GerarSWF') !== -1 &&
         arr.textContent.indexOf(pId)        !== -1 &&
         arr.textContent.indexOf(pFile)      !== -1 && 
         arr.textContent.indexOf(pWidth)     !== -1 && 
         arr.textContent.indexOf(pHeight)    !== -1 )  {
        
        var parent = arr.parentNode;
        var obj = document.createElement('object');
        obj.type = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
        obj.id = pId;
        obj.data = pFile;
        obj.width = pWidth;
        obj.height = pHeight;
        
        var param1 = document.createElement('param');
        var param2 = document.createElement('param');
        var param3 = document.createElement('param');
        
        param1.name = 'movie';
        param2.name = 'menu';
        param3.name = 'wmode';
        
        param1.value = pFile;
        param2.value = 'false';
        param3.value = 'transparent';
        
        var embed = document.createElement('embed');
        embed.src = pFile;
        embed.type = obj.type;
        embed.menu = param2.menu;
        embed.wmode = param3.wmode;
        embed.quality = 'hight';
        embed.id = pId;
        embed.width = pWidth;
        embed.height = pHeight;
        
        obj.appendChild(param1);
        obj.appendChild(param2);
        obj.appendChild(param3);
        obj.appendChild(embed);
        
        parent.appendChild(obj);
        parent.removeChild(arr);
      }
    });
  });
};
</script>

<div id="a">
  <script>GerarSWF('id01','data.txt',10,10);</script>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <div id="c">
    <script>GerarSWF('id02','data2.txt',20,20);</script>
  </div>
  <div id="d">
    <script>GerarSWF('if00','file1.doc',100,1);</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Obs:** A deve ser declarada dentro da tag `head` da página.

> Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/zfnkpgaz/)

Comment: de qualquer forma eu teria q inserir essas div no local onde estiver a tag <script> e ai a sua função funcionaria. A minha grande duvida é como inserir algo onde o nome id ou a tag não é sempre a mesma? A unica coisa constante é ter q inserir dentro do mesmo elemento tag q está sendo chamada a função <script>GerarSWF()</script>

Comment: @SuperMax Desenvolvi outra maneira, conforme você explicou no comentário, dê uma analisada.

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou muito bem. Só não entendi pq 3 itens não foram escritos no embed::          embed.menu = param2.menu;
        embed.wmode = param3.wmode;
        embed.quality = 'high'; . Mas creio q não deve ser um problema